# Print statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to compare two columns of different tables. I have two tables Books_status which have book_id and count which gives total no of books, and another table is Books_course which have two columns book_id and mini which gives minimum no. of books.  I want to compare count from Books_status and mini from books_course.

```
create trigger alarm after update on Books_status for each row 
    -> begin
    -> declare cnt123 integer;
    -> declare mini integer;
    -> select count into cnt123 from Books_status where book_id=new.book_id;
    -> select minimum into mini from Books_course where book_id=new.book_id;
    -> if( mini > cnt123 ) then select 'order books' as '';
    -> else select 'no issue' as '';
    -> end |
```

and its giving me error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
```

Comment: Even if you'll fix the current error: a trigger isn't allowed to return a result set, see [manual, restrictions on triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions). You'll got to find another way for your main problem.

Comment: The current error is caused by the missing `END IF` of your `IF` statement: [manual, IF syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html). But adding that will give you `Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`, as I said before.

Comment: so can you please give the solution????what can i do to fix my problem??

Comment: How often should an order occur? What about a simple query that lists all books that got to be ordered. You can execute this query as you want and display the results at a place where it makes most sense to your application.

Comment: sorry dear but i am not getting you...iam new to mysql.

Comment: Usually one's using nice frontends to the database, not working with plain sql statements.